# Symbolic links inside linked folder

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

I'm using symbolic link of one `folder (A)` to another folder so that the server program can load the things in `folder A`, this works well. But the problem I'm having is if I create symbolic links inside the `folder A` to sub folders then the server fails to load those sub folders that contain symbolic links.

Is what I'm trying to do supposed to work?

I'm using this shell extension to create the links:
http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html

I'm using Windows 10 64bit

Pic: 
imgur.com/a/x7sNl1S . In red color is the folder symbolic link and in blue color is the files symbolic links

Comment: Are you creating symbolic links in the original folder A or in the symbolic folder A?

Comment: In the original

Comment: Just a thought, but as a small suggestion, you may wish to clarify the individual steps you are taking. Using Link Shell Extension, the only way I was able to get similar behavior to what you describe, given folders `A`, `B` and `C`, was to paste e.g. folder `C` into a symbolic link of e.g. folder `A` or folder `B`. Dropping a symbolic link of folder `C` *directly* into e.g. folder `B` (i.e. not through a symbolic link to folder `B`) didn't cause any errors, even if folder `B` was symbolically linked to folder `A`.

Comment: I'll try to clarify. First I link the folder A to the server programs folder so that server can load the sub folders in folder A. Then I create a link of some of the files in one sub folder of A to another sub folder of A. When server tries to load one of those sub folders of folder A that contains links there's errors

Comment: I made image of the problem, better showing picture than trying to explain. Here's the link: https://imgur.com/a/x7sNl1S . In red color is the folder symbolic link and in blue color is the files symbolic links